# Python regex find all single alphabetical characters

Tags: python, regex, character, alphabetical

I want to find all indexes for each occurrence of single alphabetical characters in a string. I don't want to catch single char html codes.

Here is my code:

```
import re
s = "fish oil B stack peanut c <b>"
words = re.finditer('\S+', s)
has_alpha = re.compile(??????).search
for word in words:
    if has_alpha(word.group()):
        print (word.start())
```

Desired output:

```
9
24
```

Comment: Thank you to all you regex geniuses who assisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your format ([as you wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169815/python-regex-find-all-single-alphabetical-characters/16170564#comment23110496_16169898)) but adding only a simple check.

```
import re
s = "fish oil B stack peanut c <b>"
words = re.finditer('\S+', s)
has_alpha = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]').search
for word in words:
    if len(word.group()) == 1 and has_alpha(word.group()):
        print (word.start())
>>> 
9
24
```

Comment: Ok this is the correct solution. Thanks Inbar and everybody else.

Answer (score 6):

This does it:

```
r'(?i)\b[a-z]\b'
```

Breaking it down:

- Case insensitive match
- A word boundary
- A letter
- A word boundary

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
for match in re.finditer(r'(?i)\b[a-z]\b', s):
   print match.start()
```

Comment: Thank you, but for various reasons I need to follow the structure shown in my question. To do that I assume I would just use has_alpha = re.compile(r'(?i)\b[a-z]\b').search?

Comment: @user2104778: Yes, absolutely.  That regex works in your original code as well as in my simplified example.

Comment: Ok, I think we are almost there. Your solution is great except it catches html codes like "<b>". I would like to avoid this if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2104778: `r'(?i)^[a-z]$'` will fix that (in your code, not in my simple case).

Comment: Richie, thank you so much for your help. Your solution works on the example I used, but doesn't work on other examples, try for ex. 'pineapple W eater ww2 finetougch v ww2bd peterbuitl ww2b <b>'. But if you add in a simple len check your solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

In the most general case I'd say:

```
re.compile(r'(?i)(?<![a-z])[a-z](?![a-z])').search
```

Using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to say "a letter not preceded by another letter nor followed by another letter".