# Python Regex to capture single character alphabeticals

Tags: python, regex, alpha

Why doesn't the below regex print True?

```
print re.compile(r'^\b[a-z]\b$').search('(s)')
```

I want to match single char alphabeticals that may have non alphanumeric characters before and after, but do not have any more alphanumeric characters anywhere in the string. So the following should be matches:

```
'b'
'b)'
'(b)'
'b,
```

and the following should be misses:

```
'b(s)'
'blah(b)'
'bb)'
'b-b'
'bb'
```

The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169815/python-regex-find-all-single-alphabetical-characters) don't work.

Comment: What is the problem here?  Doesn't it work already?

Comment: sorry devnull, I had the wrong input string. Check it now, it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?  You are putting anchors to ensure that the input is 1 char, how would it match a larger string?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what ^ and $ mean. I wanted it to start looking at the start of the string for \b, then find [a-z], then \b followed immediately by the end of the string.

Comment: @user2104778 What is the actual pattern you are trying to match?

Comment: Your question is still rather vague.  I'd suggest that you ake a break, think about what you want to ask.  Put it on a piece of paper, read it a couple of times before posting.

Comment: Ok devnull I updated the question. Specifically: I want to match single char alphabeticals that may have non alphanumeric characters before and after, but do not have any more alphanumeric characters anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the answer:

```
print re.compile(^[(,\[]?[a-z][),;\]]?[,;]?$).search('(s)')
```

It catches a variety of complex patterns for single character alphanumerics. I realize this is different than what I asked for but in reality it works better.

Answer (score 2):

The `^` at the begining and `$` at the end cause the expression to match only if the *entire string* is a single character. (Thus, they make each `\b` obsolete.) Remove the anchors to match inside a larger string:

```
print re.compile(r'\b[a-z]\b').search('b(s)')
```

Alternatively, ensure only one character like:

```
print re.compile(r'^\W*[a-z]\W*$').match('b(s)')
```

Note that in the first case, `'b-b'` and `'blah(b)'` will match because they contain single alphabetical characters not touching others inside them. In the second case, `'b(s)'` will not be a match, because it contains two alphabetical characters, but the other four cases will match correctly, and all of the no-match cases will return None (false logical value) as intended.

Comment: I am sorry but I realized I asked the opposite of what I wanted. I do not want to match 'b(s)', but I do want to match '(s)'. See updated question.